# Displaying non-Object variables on Visual force page

Tags: visualforce, outputfield

I know this is the format for displaying outputs on to VF pages

```
<apex:pageBlock title="CustomObject">
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:outputField value="{! CustomObject.var1 }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! CustomObject.var2 }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! CustomObject.var3 }"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{! CustomObject.var4 }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I was wondering if we can display independent variable values . for example-

```
<apex:outputField value="{!var5 }"/>
```

**where var5 is an int value calculated in the custom controller and is not an attribute of the custom object.**

Answer (score 5):

`<apex:outputField value="{!var5 }"/>`

change this into

`<apex:outputText value="{!var5 }"/>`

It will work for you. `apex:outputfield` works with Object field while displaying controller variable you can use `apex:outputText`

Comment: Can i display a collection(List) of values using Output Text?? How can I do this?

Comment: to display a list you need to use apex:repeat.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display any integer values or string values.

Use `apex:outputText`

`<apex:outputText value="{!var5}"/>`

`<apex:outfield>` bind with only sobject's field

Display `List<String> lstString = new List<String>();` in VF page.

```
<apex:repat value="{!lstString }" var="str"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!str}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Can i display a collection(List) of values using Output Text?? How can I do this?

Comment: Yes you can. Updated my ans above.